# Searching for a Compilation of Halachot and Minhagim Originating from the Zohar

Tags: product-recommendation, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, halachic-development

The end of [this article](https://www.ou.org/torah/files/r-manning-halacha-and-kabbala-2.pdf) lists a selection of halachot sourced in the Zohar, Arizal or other kabbalistic writings. Are there any exhaustive compilations of such halachot and/or minhagim, specifically of those that come directly from the Zohar?

Comment: There is a set of sefarim called שלחן ערוך הזהר that I've seen sitting on a shelf in one of the Shuls I used to daven at. I believe it is what you are looking for, but if someone else wants to confirm (I didn't really look in it much), that would make for a good answer.